# Issues with Dygraphs in IE

Tags: dygraphs

I'm having issues getting dygraphs working in IE.

example: http://www.mytrails.com.au/trails_dg.php?tid=1000519

It's working in all other major browsers (Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome)

I'm testing it in IE8 in Windows 7. It will draw the graph very slowly but rollover functionality doesn't work. Then sometimes it will just draw the axis' and not the graph.

I have added the following code to my page as instructed on the dygraphs page (http://dygraphs.com/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9"> 
<!--[if IE]><script src="path/to/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

but I still get the same results.

I would really like to use Dygraphs as I love the highlight functionality (when it works :).

Can anyone suggest why it might not be working or a really good javascript alternative?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It works fine for me.  Doing exactly what you are.  Maybe check you have latest versions.  You've seen this?  http://blog.dygraphs.com/2011/09/dygraphs-and-ie9.html